# StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>):

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I cant able to retrive the data from Firestore and getting Error as below,

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library
> ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════ The following
> assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder(dirty,
> state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot,
> AsyncSnapshot>#e568b): A build function returned null.
>
> The offending widget is: StreamBuilder Build functions
> must never return null.
>
> To return an empty space that causes the building widget to fill
> available room, return "Container()". To return an empty space that
> takes as little room as possible, return "Container(width: 0.0,
> height: 0.0)".
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was:    StreamBuilder
> file:...dart:140:15 When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
>
> #0      debugWidgetBuilderValue. (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:300:7)
> #1      _Closure.call (dart:core-patch/function.dart)
> #2      debugWidgetBuilderValue (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:321:4)
> #3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4569:7)
> #4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4737:11) ...

---

Below is my code.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: Firestore.instance.collection("currency").snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData){
                      print('test pharse');
                       Text("Loading.....");}
                    else {
                      List<DropdownMenuItem> currencyItems = [];
                      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
                        DocumentSnapshot snap = snapshot.data.documents[i];
                        currencyItems.add(
                          DropdownMenuItem(
                            child: Text(
                              snap.documentID,
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                            ),
                            value: "${snap.documentID}",
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Icon(Icons.mail,
                              size: 25.0, color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                          SizedBox(width: 50.0),
                          DropdownButton(
                            items: currencyItems,
                            onChanged: (currencyValue) {
                              final snackBar = SnackBar(
                                content: Text(
                                  'Selected Currency value is $currencyValue',
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                                ),
                              );
                              Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
                              setState(() {
                                selectedCurrency = currencyValue;
                              });
                            },
                            value: selectedCurrency,
                            isExpanded: false,
                            hint: new Text(
                              "Choose Currency Type",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff11b719)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }
                  }),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `return` before the `Text` widget in the `!snapshot.hasData` section of the `StreamBuilder`

```dart
if (!snapshot.hasData){
    print('test phrase');
    return Text("Loading.....");
}
```

Comment: I used the return statement, in that case, I didn't get any error and i am getting the output as Loading....
I have data in my database. my screenshot link.
https://ibb.co/QKczmNQ

Comment: My understanding is that your problem with "Exception caught by widget library" is resolved. If so, consider approving this answer. If not, update the question with your actual problem or consider opening a new question with new problems that you encounter in the future